# How to print an array in the form of key-value pairs in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, key-value

I have a collection of arrays such as

```
 a = [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]) array([0, 1, 2, 3]) array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
     array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]) array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9])
```

Is there any way to show this result is the form of key-value pairs like

```
[[(0),(1,2,3,4)],[(1),(0,2,3)],[(2),(0,1,3,4)],[(3),(0,1,2,4,5,6,7,8)]
[(4),(0,2,3,5,8,9)]]
```

`i` will get increment by 1 in the key and that value will be not included in the values list

---

I tried like this, but not able to put it into the required form.

```
c = [id for id in b if id != i] for i, b in enumerate(a)]
```

Comment: Start with `[(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(a)]` and change the types of `i` and `x` as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension with `enumerate` is one way. Note the comma after each single-item key. This represents that the object type is a *tuple* of length 1.

```
from numpy import array

a = [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
     array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9])]

res = [[(i,), tuple(j for j in arr if j != i)] for i, arr in enumerate(a)]

# [[(0,), (1, 2, 3, 4)],
#  [(1,), (0, 2, 3)],
#  [(2,), (0, 1, 3, 4)],
#  [(3,), (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)],
#  [(4,), (0, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9)]]
```

Alternatively, you can create a dictionary:

```
res_dict = {i: tuple(j for j in arr if j != i) for i, arr in enumerate(a)}

# {0: (1, 2, 3, 4),
#  1: (0, 2, 3),
#  2: (0, 1, 3, 4),
#  3: (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
#  4: (0, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9)}
```

Comment: delete removes values at the supplied index, not the value itself.

Comment: Ah better,... ++

Answer (score 0):

You can try numpy approach:

```
import numpy as np

a = [np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),np.array([0, 1, 2, 3]),np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]),
     np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), np.array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9])]

print([[(i,),tuple(np.delete(j,np.argwhere(j==i)))] for i,j in enumerate(a)])
```

output:

```
[[(0,), (1, 2, 3, 4)], [(1,), (0, 2, 3)], [(2,), (0, 1, 3, 4)], [(3,), (0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)], [(4,), (0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 9)]]
```